# раскрывающийся список (ExpandableListView) + БД android

Tags: android, база-данных, expandablelistview

Здравствуйте. Возникла следующая проблема, имеется база данных которая содержит таблицу с полями наименование оборудования(name_equipment) и расположение (locations), нужно создать раскрывающийся список, где сам список будет состоять из расположение (locations), а для каждого расположения будут дочерние элементы (name_equipment). Проблема в том, что для реализации раскрывающего списка(как я понял) дочерние элементы должны находиться в новом листе. Пример:

```
public class ListData {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> loadData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expDetails = new HashMap<>();

        //Лист для списка "OOP языки программирования"
        List<String> oopLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
        oopLanguages.add("Java");
        oopLanguages.add("C++");
        oopLanguages.add("C#");
        oopLanguages.add("Python");
        oopLanguages.add("Scala");

        //Лист для списка "Structured языки программирования"
        List<String> structuredLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
        structuredLanguages.add("ALGOL");
        structuredLanguages.add("COBOL");
        structuredLanguages.add("QBasic");
        structuredLanguages.add("COMAL");
        structuredLanguages.add("LEAP");

        //Лист для списка "Functional языки программирования"
        List<String> functionalLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
        functionalLanguages.add("Haskell");
        functionalLanguages.add("Miranda");
        functionalLanguages.add("Curry");
        functionalLanguages.add("Clean");
        functionalLanguages.add("Joy");

        expDetails.put("OOP языки программирования", oopLanguages);
        expDetails.put("Structured языки программирования", structuredLanguages);
        expDetails.put("Functional языки программирования", functionalLanguages);

        return expDetails;
    }
}
```

P/s В этой базе данных 500 записей места расположения и для каждого место расположения по 300 наименований оборудования. Я не смогу вручную создать 500 переменных. 
Подскажите как можно реализовать такое??
Код беру из [этой статьи](http://javadevblog.com/primer-sozdaniya-expandablelistview-v-android.html)

Comment: не вижу в примере никакой работы с БД, почему она упоминается в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте про коллекции - работайте с курсором!
Используйте один из адаптеров для ExpandableListView и будет Вам счастье :)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html